# Can a URL have an asterisk?

Tags: http, url

I notice Wikipedia allows them in their URLs, is it legit or does anyone know where it will give me problems?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's legit and intended to be a delimiter ; see [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

Answer (score 12):

As per http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt YES, you can.

> > ...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

refer: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: You are citing a really ancient document. The latest and greatest is RFC 3986.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. All of the `sub-delims` characters can be used as is in the path. Sub-delimiters include the asterisk (`*`) character:

```
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

There are several types of URIs, but in general, a path is defined as a set of segments separated by a slash:

```
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
```

The segments are composed of characters (`segment-nz` cannot be empty):

```
segment       = *pchar
segment-nz    = 1*pchar
```

And `pchar` includes `sub-delims`:

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

Reference: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A