# What is the meaning of the URL

Tags: html, url, web-applications

There is a * in the path of the following URL. Does it have special purpose?

```
<a href="news/a/h1/t/*http://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E6%B2%B9%E5%83%B9%E9%AB%98-%E7%B6%93%E6%BF%9F%E9%83%A8%E6%93%AC%E6%94%B9-%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F-%E5%8D%BB%E6%9C%AA%E5%BF%85%E4%BE%BF%E5%AE%9C-062658903.html" title="..." hp="news_a_1_1t">...</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: It is just a regular character. See: [`Can an URL have an asterisk?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644092/can-an-url-have-an-asterisk).

Comment: you sure that's a working link ??

Comment: The link is from http://tw.yahoo.com/

Answer (score 1):

The most probable explanation is that some kind of parsing is taking place using javascript. Where did you find that?

Comment: yeap, tracking stuff for statistics and target advertising etc :)

Answer (score 1):

If i'm correct it is called URLmapping, it uses some kind of framework to fill in the asterisk with dynamics