# Download public file from Google Drive - Golang

Tags: download, go, google-drive-api

I have a zip file stored on Google Drive (it is shared publicly). I want to know how to download it in Golang. This current code just creates a blank file named "file.zip":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2Q7X-dUtUBebElySVh1ZS1iaTQ"
    fileName := "file.zip"
    fmt.Println("Downloading file...")

    output, err := os.Create(fileName)
    defer output.Close()

    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while downloading", url, "-", eerrror)
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    n, err := io.Copy(output, response.Body)

    fmt.Println(n, "bytes downloaded")
}
```

Comment: what does the error variable have?

Comment: I tried running your code locally. The response status is 403 Forbidden. I don't know what is causing that though. Also, never use "error" as a variable. You are shadowing the universe "error" type.

Comment: Huh, well why would it say that? I shared the file publically. And thanks for the heads up about the error variable, I will change it to err.

Comment: It's possible that Google is doing something which interacts with the browser somehow. Maybe they're detecting that you're not using a browser and rejecting you on that basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.
Use: https://googledrive.com/host/*ID*

Instead of: https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=*ID*

Comment: Thank You so much!!! I have been searching the internet for 2 hours to solve this problem and you have been the only one to do this.
Can you please provide the source of your answer?

Comment: Sorry, it was awhile ago. I think it was some Google help page relating to something else and I figured I would see if it would work for this as well, and it did.

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be a bug, either with Google drive or with golang, I'm not sure which!

The problem is that the first URL you gave redirects to a second URL which looks something like this

`https://doc-00-c8-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/8i67l6m6cdojptjuh883mu0qqmtptds1/1376330400000/06448503420061938118/*/0B2Q7X-dUtUBebElySVh1ZS1iaTQ?h=16653014193614665626&e=download`

Note the `*` in the URL which is legal according to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644092/can-an-url-have-an-asterisk). However it does have a special meaning as a delimeter.

Go fetches the URL with the `*` encoded as `%2A` like this

`https://doc-00-c8-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/8i67l6m6cdojptjuh883mu0qqmtptds1/1376330400000/06448503420061938118/%2A/0B2Q7X-dUtUBebElySVh1ZS1iaTQ?h=16653014193614665626&e=download`

Which Google replies "403 Forbidden" to.

Google doesn't seem to be resolving the `%2A` into a `*`.

According to [this article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) reserved characters (of which `*` is one) used in a URI scheme: if it is necessary to use that character for some other purpose, then the character must be percent-encoded.

I'm not enough of an expert on this to say who is right, but since Google wrote both parts of the problem it is definitely their fault somewhere!

[Here is the program I was using for testing](http://play.golang.org/p/9klBH2Wob0)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have found a solution. I will post it soon.

Comment: It's 2015, and google still does not accept `%2A`. It was a hellish experience to track down the problem, since traffic is secured with HTTPS. Thanks for this answer, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I'm still investigating on why this is happening, in the meanwhile you can use this workaround:

http://play.golang.org/p/SzGBAiZdGJ

CheckRedirect is called when a redirect happens and you can add an Opaque path to avoid having the URL url-encoded.

Francesc

Comment: This worked with the CheckRedirect. FYI, use the Drive url now: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=ID

Comment: Also, use the ID in the share URL, not the actual file ID.