# Golang http Get empty response.Body

Tags: http, web, go, google-drive-api

I am running into a problem that for certain urls, code in Golang is not retrieving the expected content. I am not posting the actual url, but it has this form and is a link to a google drive file download `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=somelongid&export=download`. If I use wget to get the file it works fine. I also have ruby code which uses `open()` and it works as well. For some reason though Golang returns an empty buffer and no error. If I use this code to fetch some "ordinary" url like a static website it works as expected and returns non-empty response.Body. Below is code I extracted out of my project to simplify and narrow where the problem could be. Below is output.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("myurlishere")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Something went wrong")
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("Body: %v\n", body)
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
}
```

Output

```
$go run main.go
Body: []
Error: <nil>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are getting an HTTP Response error.

`http.Get` **will not** return an error if, for example, the server answers with a `404 - Not Found`, or `400 - Bad Request`. It is because they are not exceptional behavior, they are valid responses from the server.

You should check `resp.StatusCode` and see that it is one in the 200 range.

You can check the different status codes in [the package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177419/download-public-file-from-google-drive-golang) suggests that there are some problems downloading from google drive with go, because they use wildcards in the url, maybe you can try using the url listed in the answer: `https://googledrive.com/host/ID`

Comment: Good idea. I am getting a 403 error, but I dont understand why. My equivalent Ruby code works as does wget on the exact same url. The only interesting thing from wget is a 302 redirect and a curious warning that makes me think maybe its that: Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.

Comment: Combining your suggestion with this gives me the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177419/download-public-file-from-google-drive-golang. Stick that in your answer and I can mark it answered