# Go - How to download a file from Google Drive without OAuth?

Tags: go, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm planning to make a console-based program to download a publicly shared file from Google Drive by just entering the file's ID using Go programming language. I want to use prasmussen's [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) utility source as a basis to my work but this utility uses OAuth and needs to sign-in your GDrive's account on a browser first before you can use it. What I actually wanted is to just use the **download function** from it to directly download files without the authentication stuff.

To make things simpler, I want the whole program to be written only to the **main package** also, don't want to include the [goptions](https://github.com/voxelbrain/goptions) stuff for displaying the program's usage.

Someone help me locate the partial codes from the sources?

Here's a publicly shared file to be downloaded:

> File Name: Getting Started.pdf
>   File ID: 0B5gMcwYHq3zkc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl
>   File Size: 1.48 MB

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Is it possible to download the files from a non-browser client without authenticating? This might be better asked on the go-nuts mailing list or on the Go forum (https://forum.golangbridge.org/) if you haven't cracked the beginning of it just yet.

Comment: I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177419/download-public-file-from-google-drive-golang) useful post so I think I'm not going to use the gdrive client utility anymore. Thanks...