# Is asterisk a valid character in URL

Tags: url, rfc

Can this be considered as a valid URL?

http://example.com/test/*

According to the spec * is considered as a reserved character.

Comment: Yes. This will lay all your doubts to rest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085992/when-should-an-asterisk-be-encoded-in-an-http-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an URL have an asterisk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644092/can-an-url-have-an-asterisk)

Comment: About the problem SE’s link parser has with `*` in URLs, see: [Percent-encoding of asterisks (*) in links](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2254/24166)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes. As you mentioned it's a [reservered character](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html), but whether you should or not is the question. As mentioned in [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/15886):

> Even though your URL scheme seems user-friendly to you, few will think to try it, and it's likely to give unpredictable results because the meaning of wildcards in URLs is hard to discern.